# Reading/Writing EFI variables on Linux in kernel mode

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, efi, uefi

I am working on Linux UEFI .I want to access the efi variables through my driver code.
Currently I'm looking linux/efi.h API like efi.get_variable().
but I'm not getting how to call those APIs with from my driver code.

```
    struct efi  efi1;
efi_init();         
    efi_char16_t *name = (efi_char16_t *)"Boot001";
    efi_guid_t *vendor = (efi_guid_t *)"8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c";
    u32 *attr = (u32 *)0x7;
    unsigned long data_size = 1024;
    void *data = NULL;

    printk("\n Showing efi info \n");
    stat = efi1.get_variable(name,vendor,attr,&data_size,data);
```

with this code I'm getting NULL value for data.
So can you suggest what should I do? or any modification?

Comment: Are you sure you can just cast `char *` to `efi_guid_t *`? And `u32 *attr = (u32 *)0x7;` looks very, very wrong. You're also using `efi1` before it has been initialized.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think you need to call `efi_init` - that's done at boot time.

Comment: @tangrs , I'm confused about how to initialize efi1 and get access to those variables, so can you suggest any modification?

Answer (score 2):

Try rewriting the code to something like this (beware, it's not tested):

```
efi_char16_t name[] = L"Boot0001";
efi_guid_t guid = EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_GUID;
u32 attr;
unsigned long data_size = 0;
u8 *data = NULL;
efi_status_t status;

/* Get real size of UEFI variable */
status = efi.get_variable(name,&guid,&attr,&data_size,data);
if (status == EFI_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
   /* Allocate data buffer of data_size bytes */
   data = (u8*)vmalloc(data_size);
   if (!data) {
       /* Your handling here */
   }

   /* Get variable contents into buffer */
   status = efi.get_variable(name,&guid,&attr,&data_size,data);
   if (status != EFI_SUCCESS) {
       /* Your handling here */
   }
   else {
       /* Variable is now in data */
   }   
} 
else if (status == EFI_NOT_FOUND) {
   /* There is no Boot0001 variable. Try Boot0000 maybe? */
} 
else {
   /* Your handling here */
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much. @CodeRush